# using opencv with c++ and c

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to process a video using opencv and c++ and the speed of execution really matters. But I saw something that might be a problem, for example canny function for C++ is defined as

`void Canny(InputArray image, OutputArray edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int apertureSize=3, bool L2gradient=false )`

and the equivalent in C is defined as

```
void cvCanny(const CvArr* image, CvArr* edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int aperture_size=3 )
```

Obviously, if I use C++, the passed to the function image will be copied every time, that makes at least 24 copies per second since I don't use only that function. If I use C function, I will not run into that problem, because no copies will be made. Is there a way to combine for example IplImage and Mat and how much will it cost me when I cast IplImage to Mat after that? And generally, will it be a good idea to use IplImage ?

Comment: `Obviously, if I use C++, the passed to the function image will be copied every time`. Doesn't seem obvious if you read the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details)

Comment: I have missed that, thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be misinterpreting what the C++ code does. If you take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details)

You will see that `InputArray` is a `const&`

```
typedef const _InputArray& InputArray;
```

> where *InputArray is a class that can be constructed from Mat, Mat_<T>, Matx<T, m, n>, std::vector<T>, std::vector<std::vector<T> >, std::vector<Mat>, std::vector<Mat*<T> >, UMat, std::vector<UMat> or double. It can also be constructed from a matrix expression.